# Does the approval flow get turned off for users if the financial institution unchecks the "User Consent Required" box and how do i test this out?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Let's say for example, I have an application that requests the customer_identifier claim (a Restricted Claim).

1. If I have my client not check the "user consent required" box [shown in the integration guide](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/launching-your-project/organize-your-integration-guide/banno-app-settings-empty.png), would [the approval flow](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/architecture/permissions/), including the dialog to permission a us access to that data, not appear?
2. Does the approval flow kick off after you redirect your first authorization request with claims to the /oidc/auth endpoint?
3. If the information that we get from the identity token in the initial token request is all that we need, would we need to store the access token for the user in order to make sure the approval flow doesn't occur on each login?

I'm wondering about this since I don't see a way to test the approval flow functionality out on Garden FI and testing out the functionality would be helpful in seeing how to handle this on the backend.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### General answer

There isn't any specific way to test this in the *Garden* demo institution since the developer dashboard for JackHenry.Dev accounts does not have the UI necessary to set the External Application's link type to *None* nor does it have the ability to check/uncheck the box for *User consent required*.

However, the good news is that neither of those are actually necessary to test because once you hand things over to Banno for the OAuth flow, everything it does in between getting called and then calling back to your app is out of your control anyways.

### More specific answers

> 1. If I have my client not check the "user consent required" box shown in the integration guide, would the approval flow, including the dialog to permission a us access to that data, not appear?

Correct. If the administrator at the financial institution sets the External Application's link type to *None* and unchecks the box for *User consent required* then the user will not see the OAuth [Consent experience](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/architecture/permissions/#consent-experience).

- Which means checking/unchecking that box is not available for plugin cards, as they use the *PluginCard* link type.

> 2. Does the approval flow kick off after you redirect your first authorization request with claims to the /oidc/auth endpoint?

Yes.

> 3. If the information that we get from the identity token in the initial token request is all that we need, would we need to store the access token for the user in order to make sure the approval flow doesn't occur on each login?

Those are separate concepts.

The consent experience approval flow wouldn't occur on each OAuth connection unless the set of scopes or claims requested have been changed since the last time the user consented.

[Access Tokens](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/tokens/#access-tokens) have a limited lifetime, so storing them beyond that lifetime wouldn't do much good. In that case, you would need to exchange a [Refresh Token](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/tokens/#refresh-tokens) for a new Access Token, as necessary.

- By the way, we have a [guide on using Refresh Tokens](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/guides/refreshtokens/).

Hanging onto the [Identity Token](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/tokens/#identity-tokens) for authenticated information about the user is fine.

Comment: Thanks Jaime! I just want to make sure that I understood what you said correctly here and to be explicit.
"Checking/unchecking that box is not available for plugin cards, as they use the PluginCard link type." Does this imply that all plugins require the consent experience?  Could there be a timeout issue here if no response?
"The consent experience approval flow wouldn't occur on each OAuth connection unless the set of scopes or claims requested have been changed since the last time the user consented." And does this imply that Banno maintains the state of what scope or claims we request?

Comment: In particular, I'm wondering about that timeout as we would want to gate access to the plugin until a user responds to the prompt and want to make it as performant as possible.  We plan on delivering some static html based on the customer information received.

Comment: Banno, as an Identity Provider, does indeed keep track of the scopes and claims requested. Plugins can't participate in the consent flow as the intent for plugins is that they are a high trust type of integration which an institution has deployed inside of its digital banking UX. The consent flow is meant more for things like the data aggregators who want to connect accountholders within an app (e.g. Venmo) to the accountholder's accounts at an institution.

Comment: Any sort of 'speed bump' or 'pre signup' experience for a plugin needs to be built into the plugin itself. The platform doesn't offer any built-in options for that sort of thing. It's fairly typical for a pre-signup scenario to include a marketing call-to-action (sign up here), followed by a Terms & Conditions speed bump, the actual sign up process, and then subsequent visits by that user show the personalized experience card face for the plugin.

Comment: This answers my question very handily! You're the best, thank you.